# How to find the Transfer Layer from a retrained Inception model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I've completed the old [Tensorflow For Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorial in Tensorflow version 1. I've retrained the Inception model to identify cropped images of faces.

I can see the results as a list of probabilities but my question is:

**How can I access the Training Layer (the layer before the Softmax layer)?**

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
    input_operation.outputs[0]: t
  })
results = np.squeeze(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
labels = load_labels(label_file)
for i in top_k:
  print(labels[i], results[i])
```

Because once I have the training layer, I want to use dimensionality reduction (PCA and/or t-SNE) to create a large data set of single face images and then used KNN (K-Nearest Neighbors) to find the closes match.

Here is [the full code to return the probabilities](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py).

Comment: Is is as simple as `output_operation.outputs[0]`?

Comment: Oh, I think it's the `results` variable after the np.squeeze, right? It returns `[2.4199039e-03 1.1817381e-02 1.3734173e-03 1.8507827e-02 2.5086382e-03
 5.3589828e-03 2.1489373e-04 ...]`

Comment: If you want to see the layer information then model.summary() or access a particular layer information then model.layers[index]. If you want to know the model weights of layer then model.layers[index].get_weights().